# How can duplicate results in a different order be removed in a Cypher response?

Tags: neo4j, duplicates, cypher

I am trying to find all the videos which 2 people commonly liked using the following cypher query

```
MATCH (p1: person)-[:LIKED]->(v)<-[:LIKED]-(p2: person)
return p1, p2, v
```

In the output each entry is listed twice, with the values of p1 and p2 being switched. Example:

```
BOB | Mary | Cat video
Mary| Bob  | Cat video
```

How can such duplicate entries combined into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to prevent duplicate results:

```
MATCH (p1: person)-[:LIKED]->(v)<-[:LIKED]-(p2: person)
WHERE ID(p1) < ID(p2)
RETURN p1, p2, v;
```

This works by requiring `p1` to have a lower native ID than `p2`.