# Duplicate combinations in neo4j response

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to find pairs of authors who wrote a paper together

```
Match (a:Author) <-- (b:Paper) --> (c:Author) 
where a<>c 
return distinct ID(a) as target, 
            ID(c) as source
```

This works, however, if a paper is written by 'ABC' and 'DEF' i'm getting 2 rows as follows:

Target        Source

'ABC'         'DEF'

'DEF'         'ABC'

I only need 1 of the above rows as the order is not important. How can this e done please?

thanks

Comment: here is a similar question that has been asked in the past... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603136/remove-duplicate-results-in-different-order-in-neo4j

Comment: Also, unless there are multiple relationships of the given type (in your case, any type) between the paper and the same author, you can omit your WHERE predicate; Cypher will not allow a and c to be the same node.